# Can someone explain me this wrapper class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

-- Visualforce page --

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="WrapperDemoClass">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapperObj}" var="Rec">
         <apex:column value="{!Rec.accObj.name}"/>
         <apex:column >
            <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!Rec.checkBox}"/>
         </apex:column>
      </apex:pageblockTable> 
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

-- Controller used --

```
public with sharing class WrapperDemoClass {
     Public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList{get;set;}
        public WrapperDemoClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        }

       Public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj(){
          List<Account> accList = [Select id,name from account limit 5];

          **WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();**

          for(Account acc: accList){
            WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(acc,false)); 
          }
          return WrapperList;
       } 

       Public Class WrapperClassEx{
         Public Account accObj{get;set;}
         Public Boolean checkBox{get;set;}

         Public WrapperClassEx(Account accRec, boolean SelectBox){
            accObj = accRec;
            checkBox = SelectBox;
         }
       }
    }
```

Thanks for the answers, i was really confused with the methods, now i atleast get the idea.

Comment: you are creating a list view with checkbox option.

Comment: Hi Tushar, i recently started salesforce and in progress. I understand why we use wrapper class, whats the end result for this, i dont understand how the code is making this work, so if you could explain the code.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever `WrapperClassEx` is being called, an instance of **WrapperClassEx Wrapper class** is created. *As a wrapper class is enhanced replica of an sObject*, When you bind Account with your Boolean field here

`Public WrapperClassEx(Account accRec, boolean SelectBox){`

This states that you are creating the replica of your Account sObject with an additional **Boolean checkBox** field. which is just adding an additional field for use associated with the Account sObject dynamically at run-time.

As you asked :

```
  **WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();**

  for(Account acc: accList){
    WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(acc,false)); 
  }
  return WrapperList;
```

Here If you try to Add account record to the wrapper class in order to bind Account record along with the checkbox value,
without **`WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();`** line, the scenario comes like a wrapper class is a class that need to be instantiated before being used, The above line **instantiates** the class and loads into memory for being used.

If you don't instantiate, the class is has not taken memory and you won't be able to add record to it here : **`WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(acc,false));`**

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Can you tell me why line number 3 is needed in controller code, what is the value for wrapperlist if this line is not present and why? it gives error without this line stating deferencing Null

Comment: Hello @Niknit, your question is answered in answer(edited).

Answer (score 3):

The visualforce page is bound to Standard 'Account' Controller and 
Extension class 'WrapperDemoClass'

In 'WrapperDemoClass ', the method getwrapperObj queries all the Account records and form an List of WrapperClassEx (An Inner class) just to send an List to VF Where each List value has a Account record and an Boolean checkbox value.

Comment: Can you tell me why line number 3 is needed in controller code, what is the value for wrapperlist if this line is not present and why? it gives error without this line stating deferencing Null